# How to call variables from other files python with classes?

Tags: python

Hi all I would like to know how to call variables (which are inside classes) from other python files. I am aware of the bellow method of doing this however it will not work if the class is called from the original file.

```
 from (insert_file_name_hear) import *
```

This a similar sample to what I'm working with:

functions.py

```
 num = 0
 num2 = 0

 class Test():

       def alt_num(self):
           global alt_num
           alt = 55

       def change(self):
           global num, num2
           num += alt_num
           num2 = num

def print_num():
     global num2
     print(num2)

def work():
     Test.alt_num(Test)
     Test.change(Test)
     print_num()
```

print.py

```
from functions import *

work()

def printing():
     print(num2)

printing()
```

When I run print.py it will accuratly print in the functions.py file however it will print 0 in the print.py file. Note: Both files are in the same folder and I am running this in Python 3.

Thanks

Comment: Note: Remove the `,` on the `print_num()` function.

Comment: your using of classes and instances is weird!  what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What they said. Using `global` like that inside methods is very... unusual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Globals you can use class variables with a little bit of effort

functions.py

```
class Test():
    num = 0
    num2 = 0
    alt = 0

    @classmethod
    def alt_num(cls):
        cls.alt = 55

    @classmethod
    def change(cls):
        cls.num += cls.alt
        cls.num2 = cls.num


def print_num():
     print(Test.num2)

def work():
     Test.alt_num()
     Test.change()
     print_num()
     Test.change()
     print_num()
     Test.change()
     print_num()
     return Test.num2
```

print.py

```
from functions import *

work()

def printing():
    print(Test.num2)

printing()
```

Note: the output of the above is

55

110

165

165

The first three come from work(), the last from printing()

Answer (score 0):

First - alt and alt_num are not defined
Second - You need to return the variable through a function to use it elsewhere

Below is how you can do this

functions.py

```
alt = 0
num = 0
num2 = 0

class Test():

      def alt_num(self):
          global alt
          alt = 55

      def change(self):
          global num, num2
          num += alt
          num2 = num

def print_num():
     global num2

def work():
     Test.alt_num(Test)
     Test.change(Test)
     print_num()
     return num2
```

print.py

```
from functions import *

def printing():
    print(work())

printing()
```

Answer (score 0):

In functions.py you declare **num2 = 0**, the rest of the manipulation of **num2** is made inside functions that do not return the new value.

The function print_num() actually prints the new value of **num2**, this is where 55 comes from in the output.

In *print.py* you are printing the **num2** that is declared on line 2 of *functions.py*

If you are only interested in **num2** after the value has been updated you could skip the printing in *functions.py*, instead return the value and print it from *print.py*.

It could look something like this.

functions.py

```
num = 0

class Test():
    def alt_num():
        global alt
        alt = 55

    def change():
        global num
        global num2
        num += alt
        num2 = num


def work():
    Test.alt_num()
    Test.change()
    return(num2)
```

print.py

```
from functions import *

def printing():
    print(work())

printing()
```